# How can I get a sequence number from an oracle database with jpaRepository?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I´m trying to get a sequence number from an oracle database using a jpaRepository.

The main problem is because I don´t have any Object in JpaRepository so I don´t really know how to solve it. The sequence number will be a Long, and I only need to return this number in my repository.

My code:

```java
@Repository
public interface InsuranceRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT INSURANCE_VOUCHER_SEQ.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
    Long findInsuranceVoucher();
}
```

I know  is wrong, but I don´t know how I should implement it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just use JDBC. Why do you want it?

Comment: Why do you want to use Spring Data JPA when you don't have an entity? Why even JPA?

Comment: Fyi spring data Jpa and spring jdbc can coexist in the same application. You don't have to do everything in jpa.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically do it, but it will be ugly. How about using `@PersistenceContext` like so:

```
@Repository
public class InsuranceDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public Long getInsuranceVoucher() {
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT INSURANCE_VOUCHER_SEQ.nextval FROM dual");
        
        return (Long) q.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to make a dummy entity that refers to the pseudo-table `dual` (I see the Oracle tag).

```
@Entity
public class Dual {
    @Id
    private String dummy;
    /* ... boilerplate ... */
}
```

Then use this entity in your repository.